# How can I use fade or any other transition effect while swapping two elements using display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, swap

I have made a simple code snippet to swap two divs using two separate buttons via javascript. Here is the code:

```js
function SwapDivsWithClick2(div1, div2) {
  d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
  d2 = document.getElementById(div2);

  d1.style.display = "block";
  d2.style.display = "none";

}
```

```css
.button1 {
  content: url("http://placehold.it/250x50/000000/FFFF00?text=CLICK+FOR+DIV1");
}

.button2 {
  content: url("http://placehold.it/250x50/000000/FFFF00?text=CLICK+FOR+DIV2");
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="buttons">
    <span><a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick2('div1','div2')"><img   class="button1 fade"/></span>
    <span><a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick2('div2','div1')"><img class="button2 fade"/></span>
  </div>
  <div id="div1" style="display: block;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300/FF0000/FFFFFF?text=div1" />
  </div>
  <div id="div2" style="display: none;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=div2" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Codepen link to the above code: http://codepen.io/misteeque/pen/qNZJLj

In the above, how can I add a transition effect like "fade" or something else when the div's are swapped? If not possible via display: none, is there any other way to achieve the transition effect?

Thank you!

Comment: `opacity` is your friend here.

Comment: are you using jQuery?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: If you are using jquery you just need to call fadeOut function in jquery: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/ (your tags seem to indicate jquery)

Comment: http://codepen.io/hendrysadrak/pen/QENJXp using opacity

Comment: yes, I am using jquery.